# NVDA screen reader not reading and getting focus within role="dialog"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility, nvda

The Below mentioned code reflects a 'Dialog' on the screen. I am using the NVDA screen Reader to read the screen. When a Dialog box is opened, the focus should go to close dialog button. Screen reader is getting focus on a close button when dialog opens but not reading the button text. Screen reader keeps reading the background.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/1uLsab5s/

```
<html>
   <body>
      <style>
         .dialog {display:none;}
      </style>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $('p.first').focus().focusin();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".dialog").show();
                $(".element").focus().focusin();
            }, 3000);
            var focusElm = $('.element');
            $(document).on('keydown click', function(e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if ($(e.target).hasClass('element')) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    if (e.shiftKey && code === 9) {
                        focusElm.focus().focusin();
                    } else if (code === 9 || code === 37 || code === 38 || code === 39 || code === 40) {
                        focusElm.focus().focusin();
                    } else if (code === 13) {
                        console.log('code 13');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
      </script>
      <p class="first" tabindex="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <p tabindex="0">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>     
      <div class="dialog" role="dialog" aria-label="dialog box">
         <button class="element" tabindex="1" title="close dialog" alt="close dialog">
         close dialog
         </button>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Late for the party! But still, I achieved to hold the focus on the dialog for jquery ui-dialog.open: function (event, ui) {
     document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if (e.key === 'Tab' || e.keyCode === '9') {
       if ($(element).dialog('isOpen')) {
        var isChildItemActive = false;
        $(element).children().each(function () {
         if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
          isChildItemActive = true;
         }
        });
        if (!isChildItemActive) {
         $(element).find(':focusable').first().focus();}   } }
     });
    },